# NAME OF ZOMBIE WEBSITE GAME

Tags: windows-7, windows, plants-vs-zombies

I am trying to identify the name of this "website" game I guess you can call it that a few buddies and myself used to play back in Junior high. Its probably not even active or online anymore but I am hoping someone would be hoping to bless me today and unlock a very very part in my brain in childhood years.
Basically it was im almost 97% sure on some sort of arcade website with a bunch of different games varying in different actions and types. This being a zombie game the obvious objective was to survive. the only controls you had were back and forth going literally horizontally on the screen you picked up different weapons as they dropped and you could get different skins you also unlocked achievements varying in different things. You could get like a mini gun or a sword or you could pick up like a helicopter shooter type thing. This game was really really fun. I am really hoping someone can help me find the name of this game. It was really simple and easy now that im 23 thinking about it. this was only like maybe 2012 or 2013 to 2014 because it would only be in computer lab we got the chance to play this game.
So to end all this off ZOMBIE WEBSITE ARCADE GAME I AM SEARCHING FOR. ONLY HORIZONTAL CONTROLS(SIDE TO SIDE)PICKUP DIFFERENT DROPPED WEAPONS AND GETTING DIFFERENT SKINS AS YOU UNLOCK KILLSTREAKS OR ACHIEVEMENTS.
WEBSITE ZOMBIE ARCADE GAME REALLY FUN SOMEONE ON HERE WILL KNOW FOR SURE! ANYONE PLEASE HELP.

Comment: Hi NDT.GARNER, you may want to take the [tour]. Unfortunately, identification questions are off-topic on this stack (unless you have a screenshot or other media from the game). You may have more like on reddit, or since the game is about zombies you could probably try on SciFi.SE instead.

Comment: Try asking over in https://www.reddit.com/r/tipofmyjoystick/ they have a format that you can fill out with the important details.